# How do you customize the 'More Information' dropdown section of profile pages in My Sites?

Tags: user-profile, my-site, user-profile-property

[image]

When you click More Information, if there is in fact more information, I want to customize what information gets put in there, can you make some of those fields always display above the More Information section? Can I make it not appear double-spaced? expand the column width limit etc. We are syncing fields like Education, Assistant and Assistant phone, Fax number and more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can modify it by affect properties of corresponding div (look at my example):

[image]

Please note the id of the target div and the modified width (I've done it with IE dev tools). Also note the BR tags - it's the reason for undesired spacing.

I suggest to add to page the hidden Content Editor Web Part and add a script inside it to modify this div content on page load via JQuery and CSS.

Comment: thanks but forgive my novice abilities - where do I go to find this? I tried editing the page via sharepoint designer but can't find a similar section in any of the aspx pages I'm finding...

Comment: you don't need SharePoint Designer for this task - just open the page in Internet Explorer 8 or later, hit F12, click on arrow in toolbar and pick any element inside desired area on page. You should see DOM tree with your selected element like in my screenshot. Or simply open page source in browser. Anyway you need it only to observe page HTML. Then you need to plan your modifications and write some JQuery/CSS. You should embed them into page somehow and the easiest way is to add it is the Content Editor WebPart - it allows to insert raw HTML inside it.